# How to add a calculated column which shows the modified date/time of an attachment?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, date-time, attachments

I have a list where each item has an attachment (or in some cases 2 attachments). I would like to add a "Last modified" column in a view which shows the date/time of the last attachment modification. I do not want to show the date/time of the record its self - only the attachment(s). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anyway to do this in the UI or SharePoint Designer.  You would need to create a custom Visual Studio solution.  A couple things you could do in Visual Studio: 1) create a Visual Studio workflow that runs each time the item is edited to get the information, or 2) create a list event receiver that accomplishes the same thing.